# Are these hacking attempts or something less sinister?

Tags: server, hacking

I just had a look through our web server error logs, and Terminal services is reporting:

"Remote session from client name a exceeded the maximum allowed failed logon attempts. The session was forcibly terminated."

Hundreds of times, every 10.5 seconds or so for a period of about 5-10 minutes, once at 2pm yesterday and once again at about 1am this morning.

We CURRENTLY have RDP open to the outside, as I am just completing the setup and now and then I/Others need to jump on from an outside office/location (VPN isn't an option)

As these are so regular, am I right in assuming that they may be the result of some sort of dictionary attack? or could something like an internal admin's hung session cause such a mass of events?

(Win Server 2008 R2)

Comment: Not necessarily a hacking attempt, but definitely something to block.

Comment: Did anybody find a way to stop these attacks/blocking attempts? Would prefer any solution without changing the RDP port(default 3389) coz thats something i need to avoid. Have to keep the RDP port open too. :( Is there any other way?

Comment: no, in the end we blocked external RDP completely at the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, sounds like it. Normally in the logs it will advise of an IP address, this may be a good indicator.

I had almost identical (but mine was via a SQL Server weakness and an open port), in the end the attacks were so constant it stole all the bandwidth (port flooding I think is the term)